# Two csv files: Change one csv by the other and pull out that line

Tags: perl, csv, awk, grep

I have two CSV files. The first is a list file, it contains the ID and names. For example

```
1127100,Acanthocolla cruciata  
1127103,Acanthocyrta haeckeli  
1127108,Acanthometra fusca
```

The second is what I want to exchange and extract the line by the first number if a match is found. The first column of numbers correspond in each file. For example

```
1127108,1,0.60042  
1127103,1,0.819671  
1127100,2,0.50421,0.527007  
10207,3,0.530422,0.624466
```

So I want to end up with CSV file like this

```
Acanthometra fusca,1,0.60042  
Acanthocyrta haeckeli,1,0.819671  
Acanthocolla cruciata,2,0.50421,0.527007
```

I tried Perl but opening two files at once proved messy. So I tried converting one of the CSV files to a string and parse it that way, but didnt work. But then I was reading about `grep` and other one-liners but I am not familiar with it. Would this be possible with grep?

This is the Perl code I tried

```
use strict;
use warnings;

 open my $csv_score, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
 open my $csv_list,  '<', "$ARGV[1]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
 open my $out, ">$ARGV[0]_final.txt" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

  my $string = <$csv_score>;

  while ( <$csv_list> ) {

    my ($find, $replace) = split /,/; 
    $string =~ s/$find/$replace/g;

         if ($string =~ m/^$replace/){
         print $out $string;
      }
  }

close $csv_score;
close $csv_list;
close $out;
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are having a problem with. If there is none, as I suspect, then you should go away and write some as Stack Overflow is a nowledge base, not a free way of getting your job done. We will help you with *specific problems* with your code, but we won't ordinarily implement a solution to your specification

Comment: @Borodin editwar! :D

Comment: That is actually pretty clear Perl code on the first glance. Did you write that yourself?

Comment: I included the perl code I was talking about.

Comment: How large are those files?

Comment: The first file is 49kB and the second file is 670kB.

Comment: Ok. So not very long. I meant rows actually. But that is fine.

Comment: First, a tip for you: Parse the names into a hash with the numbers as keys. Then use that when reading the other file. I'm going to answer with a very different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was failing because you only read the first line from the `$csv_score` file, and you tried to print `$string` every time it is changed. You also failed to remove the newline from the end of the lines from your `$csv_list` file. If you fix those things then it looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $csv_score, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
open my $csv_list, '<', "$ARGV[1]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
open my $out, ">$ARGV[0]_final.txt" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

my $string = do {
    local $/;
    <$csv_score>;
};

while ( <$csv_list> ) {
    chomp;

    my ( $find, $replace ) = split /,/;
    $string =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
}

print $out $string;

close $csv_score;
close $csv_list;
close $out;
```

#### output

```
Acanthometra fusca,1,0.60042
Acanthocyrta haeckeli,1,0.819671
Acanthocolla cruciata,2,0.50421,0.527007
10207,3,0.530422,0.624466
```

However that's not a safe way of doing things, as IDs may be found elsewhere than at the start of a line

I would build a hash out of the `$csv_list` file like this, which also makes the program more concise

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

my %ids;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1];
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my ($id, $name) = split /,/;
        $ids{$id} = $name;
    }
}

open my $in_fh,  '<',  $ARGV[0];
open my $out_fh, '>', "$ARGV[0]_final.txt";

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    s{^(\d+)}{$ids{$1} // $1}e;
    print $out_fh $_;
}
```

The output is identical to that of the first program above

Comment: beat me to it! I would have added a warning perhaps in case IDs occur in one of the files that are not in the other - but probably unnecessary or an exercise for OP ;)

Answer (score 3):

The general purpose text processing tool that comes with all UNIX installations is named `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{m[$1]=$2;next} $1=m[$1]' file1 file2
Acanthometra fusca,1,0.60042
Acanthocyrta haeckeli,1,0.819671
Acanthocolla cruciata,2,0.50421,0.527007
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code as written is that you only do this once:

```
my $string = <$csv_score>;
```

This reads *one line* from `$csv_score` and you don't ever use the rest.

I would suggest that you need to:

- Read the first file into a hash
- Iterate the second file, and do a replace on the first column.
- using `Text::CSV` is generally a good idea for processing it, but it doesn't *seem* to be necessary for your example.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } );

my %replace;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    last if $row->[0] =~ m/NEXT/;
    $replace{ $row->[0] } = $row->[1];
}

print Dumper \%replace;

my $search = join( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %replace );
$search =~ qr/($search)/;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    $row->[0] =~ s/^($search)$/$replace{$1}/;
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
1127100,Acanthocolla cruciata  
1127103,Acanthocyrta haeckeli  
1127108,Acanthometra fusca 
NEXT
1127108,1,0.60042  
1127103,1,0.819671  
1127100,2,0.50421,0.527007  
10207,3,0.530422,0.624466
```

Note - this still prints that last line of your source content:

```
"Acanthometra fusca ",1,"0.60042  "
"Acanthocyrta haeckeli  ",1,"0.819671  "
"Acanthocolla cruciata  ",2,0.50421,"0.527007  "
```

(Your data contained whitespace, so `Text::CSV` wraps it in quotes)

If you want to discard that, then you could test if the replace actually occurred:

```
if ( $row->[0] =~ s/^($search)$/$replace{$1}/ ) {
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );
    print "\n";
}
```

(And you can of course, keep on using `split /,/` if you're sure you won't have any of the whacky things that `CSV` supports normally).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to provide a very different approach.

Let's say you are way more comfortable with databases than with Perl's data structures. You can use [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) to turn your CSV files into kind of relational databases. It uses Text::CSV under the hood (hat tip to @Sobrique). You will need to install it from CPAN as it's not bundled in the default [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) distribution though.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer; # for p
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, { f_ext => '.csv' } );
$dbh->{csv_tables}->{names}   = { col_names => [qw/id name/] };
$dbh->{csv_tables}->{numbers} = { col_names => [qw/id int float/] };

my $sth_select = $dbh->prepare(<<'SQL');
SELECT names.name, numbers.int, numbers.float
FROM names
JOIN numbers ON names.id = numbers.id
SQL

# column types will be silently discarded
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE result ( name CHAR(255), int INTEGER, float INTEGER )');
my $sth_insert = 
  $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO result ( name, int, float ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? ) ');

$sth_select->execute;
while (my @res = $sth_select->fetchrow_array ) {
  p @res;
  $sth_insert->execute(@res);
}
```

What this does is set up column names for the two *tables* (your CSV files) as those do not have a first row with names. I made the names up based on the data types. It will then create a new *table* (CSV file) named `result` and fill it by writing one row at a time.

At the same time it will output data (for debugging purposes) to `STDERR` through [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer).

```
[
    [0] "Acanthocolla cruciata",
    [1] 2,
    [2] 0.50421
]
[
    [0] "Acanthocyrta haeckeli",
    [1] 1,
    [2] 0.819671
]
[
    [0] "Acanthometra fusca",
    [1] 1,
    [2] 0.60042
]
```

The resulting file looks like this:

```
$ cat scratch/result.csv 
name,int,float
"Acanthocolla cruciata",2,0.50421
"Acanthocyrta haeckeli",1,0.819671
"Acanthometra fusca",1,0.60042
```